# Excel formula, adding title to each row below it

Tags: excel, vba

**So I got something like this (all in column A, seperate rows):**

Title01

atext atext atext atext atext

btext btext btext btext btext

ctext ctext ctext ctext ctext

title02

atext atext atext atext atext

btext btext btext btext btext

ctext ctext ctext ctext ctext

title03

atext atext atext atext atext

btext btext btext btext btext

ctext ctext ctext ctext ctext

**And I need solution to change it like this:**

Title01

Title01 - atext atext atext atext atext

Title01 - btext btext btext btext btext

Title01 - ctext ctext ctext ctext ctext

Title02

Title02 - atext atext atext atext atext

Title02 - btext btext btext btext btext

Title02 - ctext ctext ctext ctext ctext

Title03

Title03 - atext atext atext atext atext

Title03 - btext btext btext btext btext

Title03 - ctext ctext ctext ctext ctext

**Basicaly - adding prefix (of title) to each column A row until next title...
Is there any ideas how can i accomplish this having about 3000 line totaly and they are not the same amout under each title...

Thank you!**

Comment: Always one title row followed by 3 rows of text?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention... Always one title row, folowed by different count of rows until next title...

Comment: So how would you tell a title from the following text?  What rule would you use?

Comment: title countains "titletext" & ".txt" extention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Into cell `B1` put the formula `=A1`
- Into cell `B2` put the formula `=IF(MID(A2, 1,5)="Title", A2, B1)`
- Fill that formula down to the last row of your data.
- Into cell `C1` put the formula `=IF(MID(A1, 1,5)="Title", A1, B1 & " - " & A1)`
- Fill down.

Now you have what you want in column C.  You can copy, then paste special > values to get rid of the formulas.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Tester()    
    Dim c as Range, ttl as string

    for each c in selection.cells
       if lcase(c.value) like "*titletext*.txt" then
          ttl = c.value
       else
          if len(c.value)>0 and len(ttl)>0 then 
              c.value = ttl & " - " & c.value
          end if
       end if
    next c
End sub
```

Comment: Damn your good! I was trying to color, count and and even modify a bunch of other codes but this is as simple as it can be and it WORKS! Thanks you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an entry in a cell "push" itself into other cells. The other cells would have to be formulas that refer back to your title. So you'd have something like

```
    A
1   Title01
2   =A1&"atext atext atext atext atext"
3   =A1&"btext btext btext btext btext"
```

and so on down the line.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have about 3000 line totaly and they are not the same amout under each title...

Comment: 3000 formulas, then. What you *can* do is to put the titles, formulas, and text all in separate columns, and make the formula smart enough to be (search up for title) & text if there IS corresponding text, and blank otherwise.